# Interrupting main thread's raw_input() from child thread

Tags: python, multithreading

I have multi-threaded Python program. The main thread responses to user's command:

```
while 1:
    try:
        cmd = raw_input(">> ")
        if cmd == "exit":
            break
        # other commands
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break

# other stuffs
```

**Question**: How do I break the while loop from other child threads?

`sys.exit()` is not an option, because there are other code outside the while loop.

Possible solutions I think of:

1. Interrupt the main thread
2. Write an "exit" to `sys.stdin`

Solution 1: I tried `thread.interrupt_main()`, but it didn't work.

Solution 2: Calling `sys.stdin.write()` won't work, neither the following code:

```
f = open(sys.stdin.name, "w")
f.write("exit")
f.close()
```

[Another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167956/) provides an answer which suggests you to spawn another process and use `subprocess.Popen.communicate()` to send commands to it. But isn't it possible to do a `communicate()` on the current process itself?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like [`select`](http://docs.python.org/library/select.html) to check when there is input on `sys.stdin`. This makes the loop not wait on `raw_input` but polling instead, and you can have a loop-condition to check if to exit the loop or not.